# Error, in comparing two sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, S  and P.

I am trying to compare the Id between two sheets. IF I the ID matches the I pull the corresponding details of the matched ID and paste them in sheet3.

For this task, First I copied the column containing the ID in my sheet "Data". Then I compared this ID with the Id in Sheet "P". After comparision, if the ID matches, then I take the complete row details of Sheet "P".

I am using the below code for this.

During my comparison, I could see that, just in one particular line 149 in my data sheet, the data I am extracting from sheet P is not getting copied according to the code.

I also, crosschecked with my  sheet "P", if they are resembling the same , but there is no problem with my data in sheet "P" as well.

Could someone help me to figure out, what is wrong with my code and why particularly in line 149, this happens. ?

```
Sub lookup()
Dim lLastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S").Select
lLastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P5:P" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("E5")
Range("G5:G" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("H5")
'Go to the destination sheet
Sheets("Data").Select
For i = 5 To lLastrow
'Search for the value on sheet2
Set rng = Sheets("P").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 5).Value & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value
Cells(i, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
Cells(i, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Offset(0, 9).Value
Cells(i, 9).Value = rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
Cells(i, 13).Value = rng.Offset(0, 6).Value
Cells(i, 14).Value = rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
Cells(i, 15).Value = rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
Cells(i, 16).Value = rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT 
[image: So here you could see that the row, 149 where the column A containing the ID must be in column B whereas it is in column A, also the column with data should actually be in column I . This is happening only with this particular row. I though the data is wrong and deleted the whole data but still with the new data in this particular row the problem exist. The data in the Shee P exist in the corresponding columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't see an exact reason why the code would fail on one row, I have taken the liberty to rewrite your code to atleast get rid of 'select', which is prone to errors. 
This code should be sturdier than the original, and might help solve this issue.

Are you doing the comparison between two specific columns? Then you could replace `UsedRange.Find` with `Columns(1).Find`.

```
Sub lookup()
 Dim lLastrow As Long
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim i As Long

'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3
With Sheets("S")
  lLastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  .Range("P5:P" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("E5")
  .Range("G5:G" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("H5")
End with

For i = 5 To lLastrow
  'Search for the value on sheet2
  With Sheets("P")
       Set rng = .Columns(1).Find(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).Value & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
  End with

  'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
  If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Data")
      .Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value
      .Cells(i, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
      .Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
      .Cells(i, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
      .Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Offset(0, 9).Value
      .Cells(i, 9).Value = rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
      .Cells(i, 13).Value = rng.Offset(0, 6).Value
      .Cells(i, 14).Value = rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
      .Cells(i, 15).Value = rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
      .Cells(i, 16).Value = rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
    End with
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: with this code, it has an different idea behind.  The code above just copies everything from sheet S and there is no comparision made between the ID. I would like to extract the columns "P" and "G" from the "S" sheet and paste them in column E and H of Data sheet. Later I compare column E of Data sheet with sheet "P" . If the ID are same, then I copy the ID in column F of data sheet. With the matched ID , I then copy the corresponding details of the rows .

Comment: The comparison was an oversight on my part. Assuming you want to check if the value from the data sheet exists in the P-sheet, this should do the trick now that I've edited it.

Comment: Now it is comparing. But I am still confused why It happens, this way that, the row 149 has the data jumbled.

Comment: It is not getting pasted according to the offset

Comment: in data sheet I have 170 rows. I will upate the sample data in a while

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151940/discussion-between-jenny-and-slaqr).

Comment: The detail that I need in my column B is in column A and the one I need in column I is in column B.

Comment: @Jenny I've responded in chat.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing. Can you try like this:

```
With Worksheets("P")
    Set rng = .UsedRange.Find(.Cells(i, 5).Value & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
end with
```

It could be working and it could be the reason for the wrong result. This is how you refer to a range object in VBA - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel

Answer (score 0):

@Vityata is correct to a point, your problem is the line below.

Change

```
Sheets("P").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 5).Value & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

to

```
Set rng = Sheets("P").Cells(i, 5)
```

You are setting "rng" variable to the value in the cell in that line of code.

Then you use this line of code, `If Not rng Is Nothing` to check if there is a value in "rng", and if there is, then move the data from Sheets("P") to Sheets("S").

You have no need of a wildcard etc.

Comment: I don't think your code is the problem, If all other rows are copying correctly, It sounds like you have a problem with your source data on Sheet P, row 149. Without seeing the actual data, its hard to identify what is wrong.

Comment: I checked with my source data as well.. I tried deleting the complete line and tried. Still I get the same issue. in the source data they are aligned properly under their respective columns